# Magento 2: How to display product image caption instead of product title below the image in product details page?

Tags: magento2, product, php, media-images, gallery

We want to replace product title/heading under product image with its caption(value in title attribute of IMG element).

The things that do need the captions are:

1. When clicking on another image in the thumbnail group on the left, the appropriate caption for that image that now appears should now be attached to the image.
2. Finally, after clicking on the big image and the lightbox or whatever that is opens, each image displayed (large size) should get the appropriate caption.

Here is the [link](https://www.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/cristalbronze-cristallin-cesele-bathroom-tumbler-and-toothbrush-glass-each-in-27-finishes.html) to one of our products.

Image below shows what I want to replace with the caption.

[image]

Could you please share some idea on how to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image caption shows from image alt tag. add alt tag text in product image.
The alt tag will show as caption.

[image]